# Any way to import MySQL tables with indexes intact?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Currently our live database server does daily downloads of large data dumps (on the order of 10GB), imports them into MySQL, normalizes the data, and builds a number of indexes (full-text indexes being particularly taxing).  This creates a significant load on the live server that we would like to offload.

Ideally we would have a separate, offline server do all this work, then simply pack up and transfer the table, with indexes intact, to the live server.  Is this possible with MySQL (or MariaDB)?  These are MyISAM tables, as we make use of the Merge functionality.

From what I've seen copying files directly is certainly not the recommended way of doing things, but can we do this if we can guarantee consistent MySQL versions across the two machines, and that the tables are not being used during the transfer?  If so, are there any other steps that would need to be taken besides copying the .frm, .MYD, and .MYI files?

Comment: To copy files around, you'd need to stop/start the MySQL daemons on both machines. Would that be problematic?

Comment: Good point.  Doing so on the live server could pose problems.  Honestly I don't know enough about how these interactions work though.  Can the daemon be restarted in such a way that new connections are held, it waits until any current connections are closed (or a timeout is reached), and then it restarts and handles the queued connections?  If so, it might be acceptable, although certainly not ideal.  Is file copying with a restart the only way to copy with indexes intact?

Comment: Is this answer not correct? http://serverfault.com/a/340976/160130

Comment: It may work, but you won't ever see official documentation telling you that doing this is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup/problem and am currently looking into replication.

The Master server will do all the number crunching, data processing is done on a non-replicated Database  DBtemp.* on the master and then moved over to the DBprod.* on the master which is replicated.

Still in setup process, so cant give results, but hopefully it reduces the load on the Slave (which is the live server)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the same lines.  I've found some other optimizations that should make this unnecessary for the moment for us, but it sounds like this sort of a setup is the 'right' way to do it.